# NodeJS: sending socket but no callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

When info.password1 and info.password2 are not the same, I send a socket:

```
if(info.password1 != info.password2) {
    socket.emit('registerError', {value: 'passwordNotTheSame'});
    console.log("Register errors");
}
```

And on the client side:

```
socket.on('registerError', function(error) {
    console.log("error!");
});
```

But when I send the socket for register with not the same passwords it won`t work, it should display in the console log 'error!':
[image: screen]

Full code:
server.js:

```
socket.on('requestRegister', function(info) {
    if(!info.username || !info.password1 || !info.password2 || !info.email) {
        socket.emit("rebuild", {value: true});
        socket.emit('startChatInfo', { rooms: rooms, users: users });
        return;
    }

    var checks = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email'];
    var check = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
        if(checks[i].trim() == "") {
            check.push(checks[i]);
        }
    }

    if(check.length != 0) {
        for(var index = 0; index < check.length; index++) {
            socket.emit('registerError', {value: check[i]});
            var indexOf = check.indexOf(check[index]);
            if(indexOf > -1) {
                check.splice(indexOf, 1);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if(info.password1 != info.password2) {
            socket.emit('registerError', {value: 'passwordNotTheSame'});
            console.log("Register errors");
        } else if(!validateEmail(info.email)) {
            socket.emit('registerError', {value: 'emailNotValid'});
        } else {
            mysql.query("SELECT COUNT(username) as founds FROM users WHERE username = "+mysql.escape(info.username)+" LIMIT 1", function(result) {
                if(result[0].founds == 0) {
                    mysql.query("INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, ip_registed, ip_last) VALUES ("+mysql.escape(info.username)+", "+mysql.escape(info.password)+", "+mysql.escape(info.email)+", "+address.address+", "+address.address+" )", function(err) {
                        socket.emit('requestLogin', {username: info.username, password: info.password});
                    });
                } else {
                    socket.emit('registerError', {value: 'usernameFull'});
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

client:

```
function register() {
    var checks = ['#inputUsernamer', '#inputPasswordr1', '#inputPasswordr2', '#inputEmailr'];
    var shakes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
        if($( ""+checks[i]+"" ).val().trim() == "") {
            shakes.push(checks[i]);
        }
    }

    for(var index = 0; index < shakes.length; index++) {
        $( ""+shakes[index]+"" ).effect( "shake" );
        var indexOf = shakes.indexOf(shakes[index]);
        if(indexOf > -1) {
            shakes.splice(indexOf, 1);
        }
    }

    if(shakes.length == 0) {
        if($("#inputPasswordr1" ).val() != $( "#inputPasswordr1" ).val()) {
            alert("De wachtwoorden komen niet overeen!");
        } else if(!validateEmail($( "#inputEmailr" ).val())){
            alert("Het email adres is niet geldig!");
        } else {
            socket.emit("requestRegister", {
                username: $( "#inputUsernamer" ).val(),
                password1: $( "#inputPasswordr1" ).val(),
                password2: $( "#inputPasswordr2" ).val(),
                email: $( "#inputEmailr" ).val()
            });
        }
    }

    socket.on('registerError', function(error) {
        console.log("error!");
    });
}
```

Comment: I have check the same code and it's work for me. Try to move socket.on('registerError'...) pice of code out of register function. Check is socket object is exists at moment when you try to add event "registerError".

Comment: try to change the code 'socket.on('registerError', function(error) {
        console.log("error!");
    });' to the begin of the register function. You are declaring the listener after you call the server function, I think that is what is wrong.